# Manage offline hour in Android

Tags: android, mobile

I want to do an Android app that submits data to a web server. This application needs to run offline and the hour of the submitted info is crutial. We can't rely on the hour provided by the client, so we are always setting it in the server side. But, when android app goes offline, we need to keep a private clock separated from the system hour (because it can be modified by the user). My question is how can i achieve this? The first solution that cames to my mind is to keep a private clock in our app, but this is going to crash when someone closes it or when shutdown occurs. There is something done to achieve this in Android? Also, we are going to use Ionic framework (suggestions accepted ;))
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [SystemClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html).

It allow you to know the time elapsed from the System startup.

Store the server timestamp and wake up you're app with [AlarmService](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). Then check if the elapsed time is correct.